# yii GridView: button to change the filtering

Tags: web-applications, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm displaying some data in GridView. I have set the default attr to be 1. I would like to add a button so that it resets the attr to 2. This is an attribute that is not displayed in the grid.

Here's my controller:

```
$model = new Model('search');
$model->unsetAttributes();
$model->attr = 1;

if (isset($_GET['Model'])){
    $model->setAttributes($_GET['Model']);
}

$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Model');

$this->render('index', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'model' => $model,
));
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

**EDIT: To clarify**

I have a model, called `Model`. This has a load of attributes, of which one is called `attr`. I have a `TbGridView` that prints the entries in `Model`. It shows all attributes except `attr`. The `attr` attribute is a flag, which as default is set to `1`. I would like to have a button that, when clicked, changes the value of `attr` to, for example, `2` --- and the `TbGridView` refreshes with the new data.

**My question is**: how can I create such a button?

**EDIT 2: Maybe this JQuery/Javascript may help?**

I've been looking at this?

```
$('#yw1').yiiGridView('update', options);
```

But not sure how to use it. I can't find an API or anything, just the source code. Any ideas?

I've been trying this:

```
$('#yw1').yiiGridView('update', {data: {attr: 2}});
```

Comment: Do you have a form on the view page or is it just a grid?  If you have a form on the view page, then you can add a hidden field for attr.  When the button is clicked, update the value of that hidden field with jQuery.  Then, when the form is submitted, the value of attr will be set when you call $model->setAttributes($_GET['Model']).

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Hi @AlexAkr, please see my edit. Does this help clarify my problem and request?

Comment: @Stephen305, alas, I am not using a form; just a regular TbGridView with nothing fancy. Nice idea though! :)